# In angular grid, I have a column with an editor template (reactive form) in inline Kendo grid. It doesn't link template control (textbox) and the form

Tags: angular, templates, kendo-ui, grid, inline

In kendo grid, I have a column with an editor template (reactive form). It doesn't link template control (textbox) and the form, because of that changes are not getting reflected in the grid and not binding the template to the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to bind the custom editor within the editor template manually, e.g.:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Name" width="200">
              <ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate let-column="column" let-formGroup="formGroup" let-isNew="isNew">
                <input #input class="k-textbox" [formControl]="formGroup.get(column.field)">
              </ng-template>
          </kendo-grid-column>
```

[EXAMPLE](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/custom-reactive-editing/)